# Hashbang and escaped fragment

Tags: jquery, seo, hashbang

So ive been investigating the whole SEO AJAX malarkey, and set up a test page here: [My Site](http://laynestaley.co.uk/test)

I used a sample code from GitHub, The hashbang `#!` works fine as you can see, but try accessing any of the pages replacing the hashbang with `?_escaped_fragment_` as Google would interpret it. The pages don't load, to a certain extent. The home page loads.

I'm guessing this one of 2 things, maybe both:

1. There is no HTML snapshot
2. The Code is wrong..

Or I'm not getting this..

The code i used is here: https://github.com/bartaz/jquery-address/tree/master/samples/crawling

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be worth looking at what headers the page actually receives when you try visiting it using `?_escaped_fragment_`

Try echoing out `$_REQUEST` using `var_export()` or `print_r()`

Comment: i added a jQuery plugin to handle hashbangs and some php to handle the request server side